# C# Regex method explains

Tags: c#, regex

```
new Regex(@"\n|\r|\\|<|>|\*|!|\$|%|;");
```

I have an regex example above, but I can not really understand what is trying to find? can anyone give me a hand please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regex matches one of the characters separated by the [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) operator `|`. There are a few special characters (like `\n` or `\r` for newline and carriage return, or `\$` for a literal dollar sign and `\*` for a literal asterisk because `$` and `*` are regex [metacharacters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html)), but other than that, it's quite straightforward.

That said, for matching a single character out of a list of valid characters, a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) is usually the better choice, not only because there is less need to escape the metacharacters:

```
new Regex(@"[\n\r\\<>*!$%;]");
```

Answer (score 2):

It'll try to match any of the special character listed: `\n`, `\r`, `\`, `<`, `>`, `*`, `!`, `$`, `%` The `|` is the regex OR operator.

Some characters need to be escaped with an extra `\` as they have a signification in the regex lanugage (`\`, `$`, ...)

Answer (score 2):

`|` in regex is an alternation operator. `A|B` means match either `A` or `B`. It can also be written using a character class - `[AB]` which also means the same thing.

The benefit of using [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) is, you don't need to escape regex meta-characters inside it, which you have to do outside, as you did for `*`. So, your regex can be shortened to:

```
new Regex(@"[\n\r\\<>*!$%;]");
```